# How to setup replica sets to docker containers using custom MongoDB Configuration file

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

I Need Your help,
I Created three docker MongoDB containers using a custom sample config file, then I need to implement replica sets to these containers, but I can't implement, and I can't access other containers IP and Port

**db.yaml**

```
storage:
  dbPath: /data/db
  journal:
    enabled: true
replication:
  replSetName: "my_replicaSet"
net:
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
  port: 26017
```

**db1.yaml**

```
storage:
  dbPath: /data/db
  journal:
    enabled: true
replication:
  replSetName: "my_replicaSet"
net:
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
  port: 28017
```

**db2.yaml**

```
storage:
  dbPath: /data/db
  journal:
    enabled: true
replication:
  replSetName: "my_replicaSet"
net:
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
  port: 29017
```

First created three docker containers using below command

**Container Name:DB**

`docker run --name DB -v /home/mahesh/Documents/Trishula/cortana/database:/etc/mongo --net my-mongo-cluster -d mongo --config /etc/mongo/db.yaml`

**Container Name:DB1**

`docker run --name DB -v /home/mahesh/Documents/Trishula/cortana/database:/etc/mongo --net my-mongo-cluster -d mongo --config /etc/mongo/db1.yaml`

**Container Name:DB2**

`docker run --name DB -v /home/mahesh/Documents/Trishula/cortana/database:/etc/mongo --net my-mongo-cluster -d mongo --config /etc/mongo/db2.yaml`

then open a docker container **DB** shell with mongo --port 26017
initiated Replica sets with `rs.initiate()`
then add another docker container as a member to that shell by defining `rs.add("DB1")`, here DB1 is the name of another container, I got the error message like this

```
my_replicaSet:PRIMARY> rs.add("DB1")
{
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1597812494, 1),
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Either all host names in a replica set configuration must be localhost references, or none must be; found 1 out of 2",
        "code" : 103,
        "codeName" : "NewReplicaSetConfigurationIncompatible",
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1597812494, 1),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
                }
        }
}
```

I also tried with given the container port and IP address which is defined in YAML file,

```
my_replicaSet:PRIMARY> rs.add("127.0.0.1:28017")
{
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1597812984, 1),
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Quorum check failed because not enough voting nodes responded; required 2 but only the following 1 voting nodes responded: 127.0.0.1:26017; the following nodes did not respond affirmatively: 127.0.0.1:28017 failed with Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:28017 :: caused by :: Connection refused",
        "code" : 74,
        "codeName" : "NodeNotFound",
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1597812984, 1),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
                }
        }
}
```

I Had Implemented replica sets with command lines, but I can't implement replica sets with custom MongoDB configuration YAML file with docker MongoDB containers, Please help, I have been working on this for the past one week...

Note: I didn't use docker-compose YAML file...

Comment: What documentation are you following?

Comment: for setting the custom MongoDB config file to Docker container, I followed this official documentation [https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo]

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to setup mongodb replicaset locally using docker, refer https://medium.com/@simone.pezzano/quick-docker-and-mongodb-replica-set-on-your-computer-5c2470012a41